# VB Continuously Transfer/dispaly data from a file to another

Tags: vb.net

My friend and I (i'm only helping) are writing a code in VB that continuously get voltage and display it; that part works correctly. The next time is to continuously transfer it to another file and have it display it. Although we can transfer the data and display it, it doesn't display continuously, we have to refresh it(click start then stop on and on) in order to view the data. Any help in figuring how to fix this is greatly appreciated, and I apologize for not posting the code as we are not allowed to.

Comment: This might be a perfect case scenario for using separate threads. One to send the data, the other one to update the label that displays the voltage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a timer to refresh the display.
I can't help much more without more context for the technology used for the UI.